# GRASS session fail to start because of g.extension failed on linux mint

Tags: grass-7.2, linux-mint

I am struggling to start any existing Grass sessions (that was working before) in Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64 bit on an Oracle virtual machine.

The following error is popping up every time I am trying to open any previously working GRASS session.

[image: Error message]

I have tried the following:

1. Uninstall GRASS 7.2 and all other grass components (GRASS Core, GUI)
   and reinstalled it.
2. Restarted the Linux after uninstalling GRASS
3. Double checked that no other GRASS session is open, or existing lock
   is not there

Still cannot use GRASS. Any idea??

Comment: does the following thread help? https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2016-September/074833.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that thread has not got any solution as well.